# Storing Array in JSON

Tags: java, json

I am working on a research project that requires storing a large amount of external data. I have settled on the JSON format, which I have never used, as a storage format. All I really need to store is a large array of data however every example of JSON I can find that has an array in it is nested inside of an object. for example:

```
{ "NumberList" : {
    "array" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }}
```

Is it possible to have only an array? Such as:

```
"array" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Without an opening and closing bracket or a surrounding object?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong. JSON can start and end with an array.
The official [JSON document](http://json.org) says

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> 1. A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> 2. An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

You can also see it through [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

In a nutshell, while you still cannot do `"array" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, you can store it like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Answer (score 18):

No, that is the way the JSON is formatted

The opening/closing `{ }` are saying this is in json (I guess kind of like `<html></html>`)

There is no reason you can't do

```
{ "array" : [1,2,3,4,5,6] }
```

What this is saying is that there is one field called array which contains an array of numbers

Comment: +1, `JSON` stands for javascript *object* notation, so you gotta have at least one object to justify naming :)

Answer (score 3):

A valid JSON object always starts with `{` and ends with `}`, and an array is enclosed within `[` and `]`. Look at http://json.org.

If it is just an array you want to store and not store a name attribute to it. You can just store it as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. For example if you are storing it in an RDBMS, you may name the column as `array` and store the value as a JSON array.

In case you want to preserve the name of the attribute, or possibly want to have more attributes, you got to use this format: `{"array" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}`

Comment: OR is wrapped in square brackets in case of arrays (ordered list of values). Look at massanishi's answer.